# How to remove "Contents hiddens" from lock screen

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, hidden

I'm currently hiding sensitive notification content from the lock screen. I did that by going in Settings>Notifications>Configure notifications>On the lock screen>Hide sensitive notification content.

Now it shows Contents hidden on my lock screen. I'd like to be able to see the notification but remove that text "Contents hiddens".

Is that possible?

Screenshot.
[image: Picture]

Thank you

Comment: Yah just go to settings>lockscreen and security>notifications on lockscreen and don't allow that app to post a notification to the lockscreen not sure what phone you have so that could be a slightly different path. If you are just trying to remove the "contents hidden" text I'm not sure there is a way at the moment. I'll look into it

Comment: @asloss I still want to see the notification, I just want to hide the text. I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: Were you able to try the solution posted ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using automation. I prefer [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), being easy to learn and free (upto 5 macros)

**Note:** Not tested on Nougat ( I don't have it)

The macro would look like this ( on the left is the macro) and on right is detailed configuration for second action *Display Notification*

[image]
[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Your messaging app (Textra in my case) generates a notification which has *hidden* in it - This is the *trigger* ( you can choose multiple apps as I see from your screenshot, you have two apps)
2. First action is to clear such notifications
3. Second action is to substitute that notification with your customised message - *you have a message* in the example

This is the bare bones macro , you can play around with it and confirm whether it suits your needs - you can customise a lot in the second action by choosing options from **`...`**

Clicking this on lock screen will *NOT* launch your messaging app. If you want that to be done create another macro, where

**Trigger:** Empty Trigger

**Action:** Launch Application → select your messaging app

**Constraints​ :** None

Name this macro whatever you like (say, launch messaging app ) and on the second action of first macro tick *Invoke macro when pressed* and choose launch messaging app

For a rooted device  ( and when Nougat gets xposed ) , [SMS Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.stephapps.smsxposed) has *hide sender , hide message* options